# Is it possible to (re-)arrange and resize windows application windows by python

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to open different applications, e.g. chrome, edge, vlc and excel via python.
Based on the amount of apps and the resolution I would like to resize the apps.
How could I access this settings with python?

I only winth TKinter stuff and think this only handles newly created windows instead of already finished apps.

Comment: You want tkinter to be able to resize other non-tkinter apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto

This will allow you to manipulate applications started by a python script you wrote or already running.
There is also a specific SO tag you can check: [pywinauto]